# Minimizing a probability

Tags: probability, self-learning, estimation

Often times in estimation we are interested in minimizing the mean square error which can be thought about in a natural way. But are there ever times when we wish to minimize other error metrics such as choosing an estimator such that the probability $\ P(|X-a|>e)$ is minimized where $\ a$ is the estimate of $\ X$ and $\ e$ approaches zero (so that the probability of some small deviation is minimal).

Where can I go to learn about these alternate error metrics and how can they be thought of in a similar sense to the classic MMSE estimators?

Comment: You always have $P(|X-a|>\varepsilon)\le \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X-a)^2]}{\varepsilon^2}$

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking at [M-estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator) and [Robust Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics). An example of such an estimator is the median. The median is minimizing the absolute distance instead of the squared distance.